# rails routes - Resource not appending _path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am attempting to use resources to auto generate routes for my resource. The namespace is admin and the resource is author. The following code seems to work for most instances.

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :author
end
```

When I run

```
rake routes
```

I get the following

```
admin_author_index GET    /admin/author(.:format)          admin/author#index
                   POST   /admin/author(.:format)          admin/author#create
  new_admin_author GET    /admin/author/new(.:format)      admin/author#new
 edit_admin_author GET    /admin/author/:id/edit(.:format) admin/author#edit
      admin_author GET    /admin/author/:id(.:format)      admin/author#show
                   PUT    /admin/author/:id(.:format)      admin/author#update
                   DELETE /admin/author/:id(.:format)      admin/author#destroy
```

From what I can tell I am expecting the named paths to have a

```
_path
```

at the end. I am rather green at this. I have searched and searched but I could just be using the wrong terms to find the answer. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

-edit- I should add that

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @author] do |f| %>
<%= f.label :first_name %>
<%= f.text_field :first_name %>

<%= f.label :last_name %>
<%= f.text_field :last_name %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Gives me errors saying it can not find admin_author_path

Comment: please paste the content of your `routes.rb`. you have `admin_author_index` defined instead of `admin_author`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append either _path or _url to these. Basically everything looks good.

So for example

```
admin_author_index GET    /admin/author(.:format)          admin/author#index
```

the helper method can be admin_author_index_path or admin_author_index_url. These helpers can be used in controllers and views to point to a controller/action or url. Read this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html to understand more.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think I was getting caught up in what I wasn't seeing!

Answer (score 1):

No. The route name does not have the `_path` suffix.

Refer to [Rails routing from inside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information. It explains routing in great detail.